# mvc model in php just echo one row

Tags: php, sql, database, class

i build a website with classes and mvc model in php but i have a problem when i want to echo data just the first row is print, there are my files
**MODEL**:

```
<?php

class post extends Dbh {


    
 public function getJob($id)
 {
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = ?');
    if(!$stmt->execute(array($id))) {
        $stmt = null;
        header("location: ../index.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();

    } 

        $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     

    return $posts;
    

 }
```

view:

```
<?php

class postView extends Post {

    public function fetchName($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["jobName"];
    }

    public function fetchCom($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["company"];
    }

    public function fetchEmail($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["email"];
    }

    public function fetchCity($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["city"];
    }

    public function fetchAdress($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["adress"];
    }

    public function fetchCat($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["categorie"];
    }
    public function fetchReq($id) {
        $postInfo = $this->getJob($id);

        echo $postInfo[0]["req"];
    }
   
}
```

and this is where i print my data:

```
<div class="jobsoffer">
            <?php
            $posts = new postView();
            ?>

           <h3><?php $posts->fetchName($_SESSION["userid"]);?></h3> 
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchCom($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3> 
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchEmail($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3> 
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchCity($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3>
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchAdress($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3> 
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchCat($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3> 
            <h3><?php $posts->fetchReq($_SESSION["userid"]); ?></h3>


             
        </div>
```

thanks for help me

i tried to use foreach but it give error or i use it in model and gives all results but i can modified it with html and all rows are Adjacent

Comment: You are doing this kinda wrong. The `extends` keyword should be understood as "is special case of", when you read the code. And it is obvious that "Post" is not a specialized "Database Handler". Instead they are completely different things. To do this correctly, you should pass the DBH as a constructor dependency in the Post.